# How to keep a specific element in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have a row of elements, but one of them, which is in the middle, should be centered. Try to run this simple snippet, the "Must be in the middle" thing is not in the middle, but I would like it to be, despite the sizes of things around it. The "text-align:center" won't help, because it puts the entire list of elements in the middle and it's not aware that I want the "the-middle" thing to be in the middle:

```css
.the-whole {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.side-thing {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
}
.the-center {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-whole">
  <div class="side-thing">
    long thing at left
  </div>
  <div class="side-thing">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="side-thing">
    b
  </div>
  <div class="the-center">
    (Must be in the Middle)
  </div>
  <div class="side-thing">
    c
  </div>
  <div class="side-thing">
    d
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you change HTML?

Answer (score 2):

If you can change HTML, than you can move left and right elements inside centered one:

```css
.the-whole {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.side-thing {
  display: inline-block;
}
.the-center {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.the-center span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-whole">

  <div class="the-center">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="side-thing">
        long thing at left
      </div>
      <div class="side-thing">
        a
      </div>
      <div class="side-thing">
        b
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>(Must be in the Middle)</span>
    <div class="right">

      <div class="side-thing">
        c
      </div>
      <div class="side-thing">
        d
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `display:flex`.

```css
.the-whole {
  display: flex;
}
.the-whole div {
  display: inline;
}
.the-whole > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.the-whole > div.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-whole">
  <div class="left">
    <div>
      long thing at left
    </div>
    <div>
      a
    </div>
    <div>
      b
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div>
      (Must be in the Middle)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>
      c
    </div>
    <div>
      d
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.the-whole {
  display: flex;
}
.side {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute remaining width equally among the left and right parts */
}
.the-left {
  text-align: right;
}
.the-right {
  text-align: left;
}
.side-thing {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.the-center {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-whole">
  <div class="the-left side">
    <div class="side-thing">long thing at left</div>
    <div class="side-thing">a</div>
    <div class="side-thing">b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="the-center">(Must be in the Middle)</div>
  <div class="the-right side">
    <div class="side-thing">c</div>
    <div class="side-thing">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to insert a new div. So you will have seven. only One in the center.

```css
#page{
 
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 }

.the-whole {
 width: 39%;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}

.side-thing {
  min-width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0.1em solid red;
}
.side-thing-left{
  min-width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 0.1em solid red;
}
.the-center {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0.1em solid green;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <id id="page">
   <div class="the-whole">
      <div class="side-thing-left">left</div>
      <div class="side-thing">a</div>
      <div class="side-thing">b</div>
     </div>
    <div class="the-center">(Must be in the Middle)</div>
     <div class="the-whole">
       <div class="side-thing-left">left</div>
      <div class="side-thing">c</div>
      <div class="side-thing">d</div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this a solution?

```
.the-whole {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.side-thing {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}
.the-center {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```